# Split points by a factor in a plotly scatter plot

Tags: r, split, plotly

Probably an easy one.

I have data points (with error bars) that I'd like to plot.
There are two levels of grouping factors: `group` and `cluster`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(cluster=rep(LETTERS[1:10],2),group=c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)),point=rnorm(20),err=runif(20,0.1,0.3))
df$group <- factor(df$group,levels=c("A","B"))
```

I'd like to plot the points where the `x-axis` is `df$cluster`, and within each `cluster` the points are color coded by `df$group` and split (so that `group` `A` point is left to `group` `B` point).

Here's what I'm trying:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=~df$cluster,y=~df$point,split=~df$group,type='scatter',mode="markers",showlegend=T,color=~df$group) %>%
  layout(legend=list(orientation="h",xanchor="center",x=0.5,y=1),xaxis=list(title=NA,zeroline=F,categoryorder="array",categoryarray=sort(unique(df$cluster)),showticklabels=T),yaxis=list(title="Val",zeroline=F)) %>%
  plotly::add_trace(error_y=list(array=df$err),showlegend=F)
```

Which gives me:
[image]

Pretty close but the only thing that's not working is splitting the points in each `cluster` by `group`.

Any idea how to get this to work? Ideally the code would be generic so that any number of group levels are split within each `cluster`, rather than a code that's specific to `A` and `B` of this example.

Comment: I'm not super well versed in plotly, but do you have a preference for `plot_ly` over `ggplotly`?

Comment: Yes definitely.  Doing this with `ggplot2` is a piece of cake.

Comment: What I'm saying is there's `ggplotly` to translate a ggplot plot into a plotly one. But I don't know if there's a reason or preference to not use `ggplotly` for this

Comment: I know what you meant. `ggplotly` is a wrapper around `ggplot` to convert it to `plotly`. But it doesn't always work very so I'm not interested in that as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love `plotly` and use it almost exclusively, but there are some nice features built into `ggplot2` that require a handful of tweaks to replicate in `plotly`.

Still, I think it's worth really getting to know some of the more detailed ins and outs if you plan on publishing interactive plots for others to review. The `R` API provides a enormous amount of control available to tweak and make every little detail perfect if you use the native syntax instead of `ggplotly`.

With that said, here's how I would tackle this problem:

---

*(Data generation code provided in question)*

```
library(plotly)    
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(cluster=rep(LETTERS[1:10],2),
                 group=c(rep("A",10),
                         rep("B",10)),
                 point=rnorm(20),
                 err=runif(20,0.1,0.3))    
df$group <- factor(df$group,levels=c("A","B"))
```

First, you need to do some manual "jittering" yourself in a systematic way. I haven't read the source code for the equivalent that does this "auto-magically" in `ggplot2` functions, but I imagine something similar to this is taking place behind the curtain.

```
## Generate a set of offsets based on the number of group
Offset <- data.frame(group = unique(df$group),
                     offset = seq(-0.1, 0.1,length.out = length(unique(df$group))))

## Join the offset to the data frame based on group
df <- merge(df,Offset,by = "group", all.x = TRUE)

## Calculate an x location
df$x_location <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$cluster)) + df$offset
```

`head(df)` post-manipulation:

```
  group cluster      point       err offset x_location
1     A       A -0.6264538 0.2641893   -0.1        0.9
2     A       B  0.1836433 0.2294120   -0.1        1.9
3     A       C -0.8356286 0.2565866   -0.1        2.9
4     A       D  1.5952808 0.2106073   -0.1        3.9
5     A       E  0.3295078 0.2059439   -0.1        4.9
6     A       F -0.8204684 0.2578712   -0.1        5.9
```

Now that you have an explicit x_location, you can use that on a scatter plot and then add in categorical tick marks/text using an array. Then, by displaying the values of interest in the `text`, you can eliminate the `x` and `y` values from the `hoverinfo` to fully cover your tracks.

```
df %>% 
  plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(x= ~x_location,y= ~point, color= ~group,
            text = ~paste0("Group ",group," - Cluster ", cluster,"<br>",round(point,2)),
            error_y = list(type = "data", array = ~err), 
            hoverinfo = "text",
            type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
  layout(hovermode = "compare",
         paper_bgcolor = 'rgba(235,235,235,0)',
         plot_bgcolor = "rgba(235,235,235,1)",
         legend=list(orientation="h",
                     xanchor="center",
                     yanchor = "bottom",
                     x=0.5,y=1,
                     bgcolor = "transparent"),
         xaxis=list(title=NA,
                    zeroline=FALSE,
                    tickmode = "array",
                    tickvals = unique(as.numeric(sort(as.factor(df$cluster)))),
                    ticktext = unique(sort(as.factor(df$cluster))),
                    gridcolor = "rgba(255,255,255,1)"),
         yaxis=list(title="Val",
                    zeroline=FALSE,
                    gridcolor = "rgba(255,255,255,1)"))
```

[image: Fake_Axis_ggplot2_styled]

Comment: Thanks @Matt Summersgill. Too bad this is not implemented in `plotly`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not well acquainted with `plotly` package. I am unsure if this meets your requirement.

But here is a work around using `unite` from `tidyr` package. Created the ***cluster-group*** pair before using with `plotly`.

```
library(tidyr)

df1 <-  df %>% unite(c('cluster','group'), col = 'clust_grp', sep = "-", remove = F)

plot_ly(df1, x=~clust_grp, y=~point, type='scatter', mode="markers", showlegend=T, color=~group) %>%
    layout(legend=list(orientation="h",xanchor="center",x=0.5,y=1),xaxis=list(title="cluster_group", 
           zeroline=F, categoryorder="array", categoryarray = sort(unique(df1$clust_grp)), showticklabels=T), yaxis=list(title="Val", zeroline=F)) %>%
               plotly::add_trace(error_y=list(array=df1$err), showlegend=F)
```

[image: Cluster-Group Pairwise]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mankind_008. It's pretty close. However, I'd prefer that each cluster have a single x-axis location and that the groups are split across x-axis location.